# Get current UTC time in actionscript

Tags: actionscript, timestamp, actionscript-2, unix-timestamp

How do I get the number of milliseconds, in UTC time, since the epoch?

Just like `myDate.getTime()` returns the milliseconds in local time, I need this in universal (UTC) time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ActionScript 2 Date object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=Part2_AS2_LangRef_1.html) has a getTimezoneOffset method that will give you the difference between UTC and the local timezone in minutes.

```
var utc = myDate.getTime() + (myDate().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Comment: What happens when you try to convert times for China (GMT+8 I assume)?